# C# Two different ways to get registry entry

Tags: c#, vb.net, registry

In an older project a value of a windows registry key is read in the following way (see [Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computer(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
var computer = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer();
return computer.Registry.GetValue(sKey, sName, null).ToString();
```

I wondered about the way this has been done, because I know to get the value of a registry entry by (see [Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(sKey, sName, null)
```

Does these implementations work in the same way or are there differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the implementations do the same thing, they access the registry, they all call the base windows api to do this. You have basically found your self a perfect example to do the same thing in 2 different ways.

However there is a difference in how you get there. If you are really interested in the difference check out the documentation

[Computer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computer(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides properties for manipulating computer components such as
>   audio, the clock, the keyboard, the file system, and so on.

[Registry Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides RegistryKey objects that represent the root keys in the
>   Windows registry, and static methods to access key/value pairs.